# What is $APPHOME in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

In many of the example shell scripts I have seen I keeping coming across an $APPHOME or $apphome variable.

Is this just a naming convention used in shell scripting for the location of an application in a sub-directory or is it something more substantial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably referring to the installation folder of the application.

Comment: why not put on your explorers hat, `echo $APPHOME; cd $APPHOME; ls -ltra` to see what is there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just as the home directory of this app.